# Puppeteer with Nativescript workaround

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to use Nativescript and puppeteer but currently it doesn't work. I tried to find another headless browser solution but i dont know if it exists for nativescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puppeteer replaces Selenium while testing browser application. For mobile you use Appium (iOS / Android), where you will set `isHeadless` capability to true.

There is already an issue at [Github repo](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-appium/issues/226) which explains how it's done.

> Set `"isHeadless":true` on desired device in `appium.capabilities.json`

Comment: Actually puppeteer is not used with Selenium, it can be used *instead* of it.

Comment: @Vaviloff Thank you for pointing, I have corrected my statement.